# Fullcalendar and Scheduler Issues with versions

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I've a problem with FullCalendar (FC) and it's plugin Scheduler (S).

Since some some months I use the version 1.2.0 (S) together with 2.6.0 (FC).

It's ok, but a new request from our users (enable/disable grouping of resources) would be greatly satisfied using the feature 'get / set options dynamically'. So I've downloaded the new versions of the libraries, 1.4.0 (S) and 3.0.1 (FC).

Here come the problems: with the normal scheduler day view it works great. But, when I open a new page, where I use the weekly view, no data is show.

I've tried everything:

- changed the versions, using the 2.7.3 (FC) with 1.3.2 (S).

  used the version of (FC) packed in the zip together with (S).

  having made some changes, I've deleted them, but the fault seems to lie in the way the libraries operate together.

I would post some code, but it's a bit complex... The scheduler is encapsulated inside a "class" and is activated using events. The whole infrastructure is part of a kind of framework and I cannot simply take a part of the code. What I'm sure is that the whole works with the older version, but no way with the new.

Up to now the only working solution is to use two versions, one for each page. But, of course, this is a kind of hack, not nice and not good for maintenance.

Here is the code used to generate the scheduler. `_schedulerType` is used to crate a daily or weekly view. Two "containers", `_schedulerOptions` and `_schedulerServices` are created outside and used to define how the scheduler is created.

```
_schedulerContainer.fullCalendar({
    local (or lang): _schedulerOptions.language,
    allDaySlot: false,
    now: _currentDay,
    selectable: true,
    editable: false,
    aspectRatio: _schedulerOptions.aspectRatio,
    scrollTime: '07:30',
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    slotLabelInterval: '01:00:00',
    slotLabelFormat: _schedulerOptions.slotLabelFormat,
    slotWidth: _schedulerOptions.slotWidth,
    nowIndicator: true,
    customButtons: (_schedulerServices.schedulerHeader !== null) ?
        _schedulerServices.schedulerHeader.createCustomButtons() :
        null,
    header: (_schedulerServices.schedulerHeader !== null) ?
        _schedulerServices.schedulerHeader.createHeader() :
        false,
    defaultView: _schedulerType,
    -------------------REMOVE-----------------------------------------
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
    resourceGroupField: _defaultOptions.groupBy,
    resourceOrder: _defaultOptions.orderBy,
    resources: 
      function (callback) {
        if (_schedulerServices.rscCallback !== null) {
          if (log) {
              console.log("reload resources inside scheduler");
          }

          callback(_schedulerServices.rscCallback.getResources());
        }
      },
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    events: 
      function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        if (_schedulerServices.evtCallback !== null) {
          if (log) {
            console.log("reload events inside scheduler");
          }
         callback(_schedulerServices.evtCallback.getEvents());
        }
      },
    -------------------REMOVE-----------------------------------------
    resourceRender: 
      function (resourceObj, element) {
        if (_schedulerServices.rscViewManager !== null) {
          return _schedulerServices.rscViewManager.requestRender(resourceObj, element);
        }
      },
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    eventRender: 
      function (eventObj, element) {
        if (_schedulerServices.evtViewManager !== null) {
          return _schedulerServices.evtViewManager.requestRender(eventObj, element);
        }
      }
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks

---

Solved!!!

After version 2.6.0, the unused options fields of the options should not be used. In my case, removing all the fields related to Resources solved the problem.